# How to make VS2010 Setup Project reuse install path of previous deployment

Tags: visual-studio-2010, windows-installer, setup-project

I made an application that is deployed using a Setup Project in Visual Studio 2010. The Setup Project is configured to remove the previous version.
When the user installs a newer version of the application, it offers to install the app in the installation folder that is specified in the Setup Project.
Is there a way to make it show the folder that is used by the previous installed version?

Answer (score 2):

When you install the application you have the option of adding a registry key, it stores information such as GUID, App Name, App Path, Policy. Before perusing the uninstall, you can simply read the registry key to get this information.

Comment: I know the install path is stored in registry by msi and my application (I store a protocol handler that must know where the executable is located). But how do I retrieve it using the Setup Project and use that in the Installation Folder dialog? Must I replace the Installation Folder Dialog with my own?

Comment: @Martin Windows Installer does store the installation directory, yet the location changes with every release of your application because Product GUID changes. The best approach is to store it yourself into `HKLM\Software\YourCompanyName\YourProductName` when you install the application and then read it when you upgrade.